# Crontab can't import packages

Tags: python, macos, cron, cron-task

I'm on MacOS Catalina and I've created a python file with the contents being just

```
import beautifulsoup
```

And the crontab is setup as:

```
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ /Users/ABC/Downloads/downloading_tables.py  >> /Users/ABC/Desktop/cron.log 2>&1
```

But the logs keep throwing the error "No module named 'beautifulsoup'"

I tried adding pip install beautiful soup in the python file but it threw a syntax error on the word install.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't believe that the problem is with crontab, if you run `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` does it install or triggers already installed error?

Comment: How does $PYTHONPATH get set for your crontab?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123499/crontab-is-not-running-my-script-catalina

Comment: Adreis, I tried that, the installation goes through.

"Requirement already satisfied"

Comment: BowlofRed, already done that, crontab has full disk access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Use command

pip install bs4

to install Beautiful Soup 
and then import as :-

from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Hope That Helps!

Comment: Thank you Samarth. This works.

How do we get this to work with third party libraries such as Quandl, though?

Comment: @diablojunk BeautifulSoup should work alongside Quandl. Just install Quandl using pip3 install quandl  and you are ready to go